# Windows 10 freeze while switching input method

Tags: windows-10, freeze, input-languages

I'm currently using Microsoft Windows 10 Enterprise Version 1703 OS Build 15063.483.

Recently I've noticed that there's a little freeze (about 3 to 5 secs) while I switching the input method (form English to Chinese).

This issue happened on one of my computer recently (was fine/no freeze before).  All the other computers with same OS and input method installed are just fine and no freezing.

I didn't install any new software these days.  And I've tried to uninstalled/reinstalled the Chinese input method but still no help.

Is there any possible cause and solution for this?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Were you using a particular program when this happened?

Comment: I have 3 input methods, one of which is IME for Japanese and no such symptoms noticed. Fluid switching with alt+shift and different kana with alt+capslock and ctrl+capslock, no delay.

Comment: @spike_66 this happened no matter what program I was using :(

Comment: @Kitet I used to switch IME fluently as well.  The freezing issue happened recently :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I decide to update my question since I've encountered this exactly same issue several times on different computers.  And I finally figured out the cause and fixed it.

> TL;DR
>   Installed too many font (several GBs) will affect certain IME performance while switching)

*(All the screenshots are in Traditional Chinese since that is the language setting of my working PC.)*

I've notice that my ["Disk Usage" would dramatically increase](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nWPca.png) while switching IME and the program freezing.  This happened every time no matter which program was freezing, including: [Skype](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fTk81.png), [Google Chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EboSC.png), even in [Windows Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5rNwi.png).

After some investigations, I finally found that the freezing was caused by too many (GBs) font files were loading by OS.  For my case, it's over 5 GB font files installed in my Windows 10.  I dunno why the font files need to load while switching IME.  But reducing the font files in OS solved the problem for me.

Hope this helps and thanks.